# sorting pairs of numbers in the list

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, math

I want to write  a program which from a list of numbers selects pairs of numbers.
But this pairs should by the sum of the smallest and the sum of the largest numbers . 
In the next step I want to sort them from the smallest to the largest to show sum of the smallest and sum of the largest numbers .
Example 1
entrance: [1, 2, 4, 8, 9]
output: The smallest pair [1, 2 = 3 ], the largest pair [8, 9 = 17]

How can I sort pairs of numbers ?

```
public class Tabli {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] numbers = {12, 36, 2, 5,12,31};

    int sum0 = numbers[0] + numbers[1];
    System.out.println(sum0);

    int sum1 =numbers[1] +numbers[2];
    System.out.println(sum1);

    int sum2 =numbers[2] +numbers[3];
    System.out.println(sum2);

    int sum3 =numbers[3] +numbers[4];
    System.out.println(sum3);

    int sum4 =numbers[4] +numbers[5];
    System.out.println("End:"+sum4);

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< numbers.length; i++) {

            sum += numbers[i];

        }
    for (int j = 0; j < (numbers.length)-8; j++) {
        sum1 += numbers[j];
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);

    }
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum1);
}
}
```

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Are you asking how you're supposed to calculate, store, and finally sort all pairs of numbers?

Comment: finally sort all pairs of numbers

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int[] numbers = {12, 36, 2, 5,12,31};
int min = numbers[0] + numbers[1]; // instantiate randomly
int max = numbers[0] + numbers[1]; // instantiate randomly
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
    min = Math.min(numbers[i] + numbers[i + 1], min);
    max = Math.max(numbers[i] + numbers[i + 1], max);
}
System.out.println(min + ", " + max);
```

The output is then:

> 7, 48

This solution is valid for any length of `numbers` array.

**Edit**

When `numbers` needs to be sorted, simply add `Arrays.sort(numbers);` right after `numbers` definition.

Comment: This only checks for pairs of adjacent numbers. The array in the question was sorted, which probably caused this confusion as this is a sufficient solution for sorted arrays. In the general case, the array isn't sorted (as you can see in the provided code).

Comment: Ach ok, I missed it, I have updated the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First sort the array

```
Arrays.sort(numbers);
```

therefore the max pair are the last 2 numbers

```
int max = numbers[numbers.length-1] + numbers[numbers.length-2];
```

and the min pair are the first 2 numbers

```
int min = numbers[0] + numbers[1];
```